Customize Native Checkout Address Field
I want to customize the native checkout page,

Display the email field after the Phone Number
Add label between the shipping address form.(For e.g Contact information, Shipping Information)
Placeholder instead of the label/Title
Please check this sample mockup image.

Please help me, Your help would be appreciated.!!!!!


You may need to get any third party module which allow you to add recaptcha at any custom form/page
OR
You can refer to this https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible
for implement recaptcha at any form/page via own code.
